# update listview when click favorites button

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, notifydatasetchanged

I want when click the button `btn` in class `ListViewAdapter`, updates my sqlite and changes the `background of btn` , When MainActivity start and the button is clicked first,is correctly. but when I scroll the list, the background of btn returns to its original state and in addition When the button is clicked for a second time no change are done.
In other words, do not update my listview. How to resolve this?

Where and how do I use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

after onclick in `ListViewAdapter`? how fetch `adapter at MyActivity` on my`ListViewAdapter`

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<myitems> worldpopulationlist = null;
private ArrayList<myitems> arraylist;
int myfavorit =0;
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
Cursor mCursor;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<myitems> worldpopulationlist) {
    mContext = context;
    this.worldpopulationlist = worldpopulationlist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<myitems>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(worldpopulationlist);
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView rank;
    TextView country;
    TextView population;
    Button btn;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return worldpopulationlist.size();
}

@Override
public myitems getItem(int position) {
    return worldpopulationlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myitems_list, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.rank = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt25);
        holder.btn=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnfavor);
        holder.country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt26);


        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.rank.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).gettitle());
    holder.country.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getshomare()+"-");

    myfavorit=worldpopulationlist.get(position).getfavoir();


    if(myfavorit==0){
        holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }

    else{
        holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star);

    }




    holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext.getApplicationContext());
            myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);

            try {
                myDbHelper.createDataBase();}                   

            catch (IOException ioe) {
                throw new Error("Unable to create database");
                    }
            try {myDbHelper.openDataBase();}        
            catch (SQLException sqle) {sqle.printStackTrace();

            }

            String rr=worldpopulationlist.get(position).getprimaryid();
            db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        switch (worldpopulationlist.get(position).getfavoir()) {
        case 0:

                mCursor= db.rawQuery("UPDATE khotbe SET favorites = 1 WHERE my_id ="+rr+"  ;",null);
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
                holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star);              
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "به لیست علاقه مندی ها اضافه شد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;
            case 1:
                mCursor= db.rawQuery("UPDATE khotbe SET favorites = 0 WHERE my_id ="+rr+"  ;",null);
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
                holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "از لیست علاقه مندی های حذف گردید", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        }
    });
```

> and class myitems

```
public class myitems {

    private String title;
    private String field_translation_id;
    private String shomare;
    private String primaryid;

    private int favorit;


    public myitems(String title,String field_translation_id,String shomare,String primaryid,int favorit){
        this.title=title;
        this.field_translation_id=field_translation_id;
        this.shomare=shomare;
        this.primaryid=primaryid;
        this.favorit=favorit;

    }

    public String gettitle(){


        return this.title;

    }

public String get_field_translation_id(){


        return this.field_translation_id;

    }

    public String getshomare()
    {


    return this.shomare;


    }
    public String getprimaryid(){


    return this.primaryid;

}

    public int getfavoir(){

        return this.favorit;


    }



}
```

and MainActivity

```
public class towkhotbe extends ActionBarActivity   {
    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;

    ListView mylist;
    ArrayList<String> iran,arr_intityid,arrshomare,primarykeyarrlist;
    String[] fa,mysid,myshomare,primarykeyarr;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor mCursor;
    int translate;
    EditText mysearch;
    int [] favorit;



    ArrayList<Integer> favor;

    ListViewAdapter adapter;


    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionbar;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter sadapter;


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tow_khotbe);


            Intent myintent=getIntent();
            translate=myintent.getExtras().getInt("translate");

        mylist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        mysearch=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtsearch);

        iran=new ArrayList<String>();
        arr_intityid=new ArrayList<String>();
        arrshomare=new ArrayList<String>();
        primarykeyarrlist=new ArrayList<String>();
        favor=new ArrayList<Integer>();


    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        try {

            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        //  contentLog.append("Database Created\n");
        }                   

        catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
                }


        try {
                                myDbHelper.openDataBase();

        }       


        catch (SQLException sqle) {

            sqle.printStackTrace();

        }

        ArrayList<myitems> arraylist = new ArrayList<myitems>();
        db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        mCursor= db.rawQuery("SELECT field_translation_id_value,title,translate,my_id,favorites  FROM khotbe"
                + " WHERE translate ="+translate+" ORDER BY field_translation_id_value ASC   ;",null);

        int i = 1;

        mCursor.moveToFirst();

        while (mCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

    //  contentLog.append("(" + i++ + ")\t\t" + mCursor.getString(1) + "\n");

            iran.add(mCursor.getString(1));
            arr_intityid.add(mCursor.getString(0));
            primarykeyarrlist.add(mCursor.getString(3));
            favor.add(mCursor.getInt(4));
            arrshomare.add(""+i++);
            mCursor.moveToNext();

    }

         fa= new String [iran.size()];
         fa=iran.toArray(fa);

           mysid= new String [arr_intityid.size()];                     
           mysid=arr_intityid.toArray(mysid);

           primarykeyarr= new String [primarykeyarrlist.size()];                        
           primarykeyarr=primarykeyarrlist.toArray(primarykeyarr);



           myshomare=new String[arrshomare.size()];
           myshomare=arrshomare.toArray(myshomare);

           favorit =new int[favor.size()];
           for (int t= 0; t < favor.size(); t++) {

               favorit[t]=favor.get(t).intValue();

        }

           mCursor.moveToPosition(0);
         for (int j = 0; j < fa.length; j++) {

               myitems qqq= new myitems(fa[j],mysid[j],myshomare[j],primarykeyarr[j],favorit[j]);

               arraylist.add(qqq);

           }

           adapter=new ListViewAdapter(this, arraylist);
           mylist.setAdapter(adapter);


           Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnfavor);
           btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(towkhotbe.this, "11111111", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });



    }
```

Comment: use notifyDatasetChanged method

Comment: @Nilesh Can be further explained that

Answer (score 0):

Use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in your favorite button's `onClick()`

**EXAMPLE**

```
Button favoriteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFavButton);
favoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        //Add or remove items to list
        ..............

        //Hey, adapter! Data set updated!
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: @ Shifar Shifz how get adapter that in MainActivity into ListViewAdapter?

Comment: You can declare `ListViewAdapter` outside the method in `Activity` and can be called any where from the class. You must read this http://luan-itworld.blogspot.in/2013/08/CustomBaseAdapterandnotifyDataSetChanged.html

Comment: @  Shifar Shifz when i use onclick in MainActivity the app not run but onclick in  ListViewAdapter is ok .why?

Comment: I think you've done some mistake in your button's `onClick()`. Post your complete Activity.

Comment: @ Shifar Shifz I have to change MainActiviyt please look it again